# $P^2(A\cap B^c)+P^2(A\cap B)+P^2(A^c)\geq \dfrac{1}{3}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> For any two events $A$ and $B$, which of the following always holds?
>
> 1. $P^2(A\cap B^c)+P^2(A\cap B)+P^2(A^c)\geq \dfrac{1}{3}$
> 2. $P^2(A\cap B^c)+P^2(A\cap B)+P^2(A^c)= \dfrac{1}{3}$
> 3. $P^2(A\cap B^c)+P^2(A\cap B)+P^2(A^c)= 1$
> 4. $P^2(A\cap B^c)+P^2(A\cap B)+P^2(A^c)\leq \dfrac{1}{3}$
>
> Here $P^2(A)=(P(A))^2$

The answer is 1. But I don't know how to get that.

Using the formula, $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$ and choosing $a=P(A\cap B^c), b=P(A\cap B), c=P(A^c)$, I got, $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+c(1-c)$. But I could not simplify $ab$.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the notation $P^2$. What does that mean? Also, this is a terrible question, since 2 and 3 both imply 1, and 2 also implies 4, so you can tell immediately that 2 and 3 are incorrect, without even doing any math.

Comment: hint: $c = 1 - (a+b)$

Comment: @Arthur sorry for your inconvenience. This was a MCQ, given in a competitive exam. Only possible guess would be $P^2(A)=(P(A))^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe first that:  $a+b+c = 1 \implies a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}= \dfrac{1}{3}$. Thus $1)$ is true by Cauchy-Buniakovski inequality.